# array_filter adds additional index in my array, how to get rid of it?

Tags: php

I have a array created from json

```
$fullResult = json_decode('[{"qid":"1", "result":"helo"}, {"qid":"2", "result":"ad"}, {"qid":"3", "result":"testing"}, {"qid":"4", "result":"dd"}]');

function filterArray($value){
    global $id;
    return ($value->qid > $id);
}

$filteredResult = array_filter($fullResult, 'filterArray');
```

The `$id` is 2

When I `echo json_encode($fullResult);`
The result is

```
[   {"qid": "1", "result": "helo"},
    {"qid": "2", "result": "ad"},
    {"qid": "3", "result": "testing"},
    {"qid": "4", "result": "dd"}    ]
```

However, when I `echo json_encode($filteredResult);` the result as below (e.g. having the additional index.

```
{  "2":{"qid":"3","result":"testing"},
   "3":{"qid":"4","result":"dd"}   }
```

I want it to be as below instead

```
[  {"qid":"3","result":"testing"},
   {"qid":"4","result":"dd"}   ]
```

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
echo json_encode($filteredResult);
```

try something along the lines of,

```
echo json_encode(array_values($filteredResult));
```

`array_values` would eliminate the unwanted indexes.

Comment: Thanks!. Two also correct value, I upvote both, not sure who to tick yet.

Comment: I uptick this one as answer, as you answered first. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

`array_filter` will retain the key. If you want to make it a simple array, you can use `array_values`

```
$filteredResult = array_values(array_filter($fullResult, 'filterArray'));

echo json_encode($filteredResult);
```

This will result to:

```
[{"qid":"3","result":"testing"},{"qid":"4","result":"dd"}]
```

Doc: [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: Thanks!. Two also correct value, I upvote both, not sure who to tick yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it by loop also.

```
$singleArray = array();

foreach ($filteredResult as $key => $value){
        $singleArray[] = $value;
}
echo json_encode($singleArray);exit;
```